# c# Selenium: Unable to SwitchTo Modal/Pop-up/iFrame

Tags: c#, selenium, iframe, css-selectors

Testing a web app using c# selenium.

Having logged in, we proceed through the application until clicking a button, a modal window appears.

We have tried (we think!) every possible option, to carry on the test on this modal window!

`<iframe id="if_OpenModalDialog" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px;"></iframe>` is the result of Inspect.

We've tried, among others:

1 `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe[name='#if_OpenModalDialog']")));`

2 `driver.SwitchTo().Frame("if_OpenModalDialog");`

3 `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);`

4 `driver.SwitchTo().Window("various names");`

Also tried WindowHandles but with no luck.

Error messages either that the frame cannot be found or that the first element on the modal cannot be found (we've tried several locating methods!).

The error for method 1 above gives `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"iframe[name='#if_OpenModalDialog']"}`

I'd really appreciate ANY ideas before I go completely around the bend!!!

Thanks

@KunduK has asked for the page source - I can't do the whole thing as it exceeds this site's limits but I hope what's below is OK.

```html
</div>
        <input type="submit" name="ModalDialog$btn_DummyUC" value="[Lang?]btn_DummyUC" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ModalDialog$btn_DummyUC&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ModalDialog_btn_DummyUC" class="Hide" />

<div id="ModalDialog_mp_OpenModalDialogUC" class="modalPopup openModalDialog">
    
    <div class="header">
        <input type="image" name="ModalDialog$btn_CloseModalDialogUC" id="ModalDialog_btn_CloseModalDialogUC" class="showImg" src="../../Images/Close.svg" onclick="ModalDialogUCReturnValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ModalDialog$btn_CloseModalDialogUC&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" />
    </div>
    <iframe id="ModalDialog_if_OpenModalDialogUC"></iframe>

</div>

        <div id="pi_Progress_pnl_PIwrapper" class="progressIndicatorWrapper">
    
    <div id="pi_Progress_up_PI" style="visibility:hidden;display:block;">
        
            <div class="ModalUpdateProgress"></div>
            <div id="pi_Progress_pnl_PI" class="ProgressUpdate">
            
                <span id="pi_Progress_lblMessage" class="Label">Processing. Please Wait...</span>
                <br />
                <br />
                <img id="pi_Progress_img_Processing" class="ProgressUpdate" src="../../Images/Logo-White.svg" alt="" />
            
        </div>
        
    </div>

</div>


    <input type="hidden" name="_IG_CSS_LINKS_" id="_IG_CSS_LINKS_" value="/rezlynx1500/WebResource.axd?d=Ub3U1EM5FpAN0E8JfdsLjzYQpC_AJjXO9yVqg56RXuhxBuC6fJghDZ6WKdjccrIqLCtvmJrVMnzcZLXaIoKeU2Y_aw6HQEoT_HGwfodiPrlh4C4PgYj7z9nayVjVqWeyXou9iN6w2Cap9Xm-_fgBEtRcVvik_JLlx4If9mZCUo7J7gDu0&amp;t=637533988920000000|../../Styles/AppStyling/ig_monthcalendar.css|../../Styles/AppStyling/ig_texteditor.css|../../Styles/AppStyling/ig_dropDown.css|../../Styles/AppStyling/ig_shared.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var Page_Validators =  new Array(document.getElementById("rev_Delegates"), document.getElementById("ctl29"), document.getElementById("ctl30"), document.getElementById("ctl31"), document.getElementById("ctl32"), document.getElementById("ctl33"));
//]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var rev_Delegates = document.all ? document.all["rev_Delegates"] : document.getElementById("rev_Delegates");
rev_Delegates.controltovalidate = "winp_Delegates";
rev_Delegates.display = "Dynamic";
rev_Delegates.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
rev_Delegates.validationexpression = "^[1-9][0-9]*$";
var ctl29 = document.all ? document.all["ctl29"] : document.getElementById("ctl29");
ctl29.controltovalidate = "winp_Nights";
ctl29.focusOnError = "t";
ctl29.errormessage = "Nights is mandatory";
ctl29.display = "Dynamic";
ctl29.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl29.initialvalue = "";
var ctl30 = document.all ? document.all["ctl30"] : document.getElementById("ctl30");
ctl30.controltovalidate = "winp_Nights";
ctl30.focusOnError = "t";
ctl30.errormessage = "Nights must be greater than zero";
ctl30.display = "Dynamic";
ctl30.type = "Double";
ctl30.decimalchar = ".";
ctl30.evaluationfunction = "CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl30.valuetocompare = "0";
ctl30.operator = "GreaterThan";
var ctl31 = document.all ? document.all["ctl31"] : document.getElementById("ctl31");
ctl31.controltovalidate = "winp_Adults";
ctl31.focusOnError = "t";
ctl31.errormessage = "Adults must be numeric";
ctl31.display = "Dynamic";
ctl31.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl31.validationexpression = "^-?((\\d+)|(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\.\\d+))$";
var ctl32 = document.all ? document.all["ctl32"] : document.getElementById("ctl32");
ctl32.controltovalidate = "winp_Children";
ctl32.focusOnError = "t";
ctl32.errormessage = "Children must be numeric";
ctl32.display = "Dynamic";
ctl32.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl32.validationexpression = "^-?((\\d+)|(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\.\\d+))$";
var ctl33 = document.all ? document.all["ctl33"] : document.getElementById("ctl33");
ctl33.controltovalidate = "winp_Infants";
ctl33.focusOnError = "t";
ctl33.errormessage = "Infants must be numeric";
ctl33.display = "Dynamic";
ctl33.evaluationfunction = "RegularExpressionValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
ctl33.validationexpression = "^-?((\\d+)|(\\d+\\.\\d+)|(\\.\\d+))$";
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
URLProfileSearch='/rezlynx1500/RLXWebForms/pro/wfrm_pro_Search.aspx'; URLCompanySearch='/rezlynx1500/RLXWebForms/com/wfrm_com_Search.aspx';NumberOfDecimalPlaces=2; NumberGroupSeparator=','; NumberDecimalSeparator='.'; MoneyDecimalPlaces=4;RegisterStayDates('dpwinp_ArrivalDate','winp_Nights','dpwinp_DepartureDate');
var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
        if (typeof(FixAjaxControls) == "function") FixAjaxControls();Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Infragistics.Web.UI.WebDatePicker, {"id":"dpwinp_ArrivalDate","name":"dpwinp_ArrivalDate","props":[[[],{"c":{"prop1":"[\"2021-3-7-0-0-0-0,,\",\"09/05/03\",\"_  0322\",\"09/05/03\",29,0,\"clwinp_ArrivalDate\",\"\",\"0,3,0,3,0,0,3,0,3,0\"]","vse":0,"prop":"1,0,,0,1,1,,,0,,,,,6,,200,,2038:2040:2032,igte_AppStylingFocus,igte_AppStylingHover,igte_AppStylingNullText,igte_AppStylingInnerFocus,igte_AppStylingInnerHover","uid":"dpwinp_ArrivalDate","buts":"igte_AppStylingButtonHover,igte_AppStylingButtonPressed,igte_AppStylingButtonDisabled,igte_AppStylingButtonFocus,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igte_customHover.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igte_customPress.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igte_customDisable.gif,"}}],,,["TextChanged:gl_UpdateDepartureDate","ValueChanged:gl_UpdateDepartureDate"]]}, null, null, $get("dpwinp_ArrivalDate"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Infragistics.Web.UI.WebMonthCalendar, {"id":"clwinp_ArrivalDate","name":"clwinp_ArrivalDate","props":[[[],{"c":{"str":"January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,","uid":"clwinp_ArrivalDate","tday":"8=Today: 09/04/2021=Today: 07/04/2021=Today: {0:d}","tdyDateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"AM","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","MaxSupportedDateTime":"\/Date(253402300799999)\/","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":false},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":1,"CalendarWeekRule":2,"FullDateTimePattern":"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss","LongDatePattern":"dd MMMM yyyy","LongTimePattern":"HH:mm:ss","MonthDayPattern":"d MMMM","PMDesignator":"PM","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss \u0027GMT\u0027","ShortDatePattern":"dd/MM/yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"HH:mm","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd\u0027T\u0027HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss\u0027Z\u0027","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"ShortestDayNames":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"DayNames":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""],"IsReadOnly":false,"NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""]},"vse":0,"anim":"500,3,300,3,0,200,3,100,3,0","dates":"2021,4,1500,1,1,2500,12,31,0","myp":"## %","img":"../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igmc_prevHover.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igmc_prevPress.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igmc_nextHover.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igmc_nextPress.gif","prop":"15,3,7,2,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,2038,2040,2039,2037,2036,,,6,5,igmc_AppStylingDay,igmc_AppStylingWeekendDay,igmc_AppStylingOtherMonthDay,igmc_AppStylingTodayDay,igmc_AppStylingSelectedDay,igmc_AppStylingWeekNumber,igmc_AppStylingHoverDay,igmc_AppStylingFocusDay,igmc_AppStylingDisabledDay,igmc_AppStylingHoverNextPrev,igmc_AppStylingPressedNextPrev,igmc_AppStylingHoverMonthYear,igmc_AppStylingPressedMonthYear,igmc_AppStylingHoverFooter,igmc_AppStylingPressedFooter,igmc_AppStylingList,igmc_AppStylingItem,igmc_AppStylingHoverItem,igmc_AppStylingSelectedItem,"}}],,,[]]}, null, null, $get("clwinp_ArrivalDate"));
});

document.getElementById('rev_Delegates').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('rev_Delegates'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl29').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl29'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl30').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl30'));
}
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Infragistics.Web.UI.WebDatePicker, {"id":"dpwinp_DepartureDate","name":"dpwinp_DepartureDate","props":[[[],{"c":{"prop1":"[\"2021-3-8-0-0-0-0,,\",\"09/05/03\",\"_  0322\",\"09/05/03\",29,0,\"clwinp_ArrivalDate\",\"\",\"0,3,0,3,0,0,3,0,3,0\"]","vse":0,"prop":"1,0,,0,1,1,,,0,,,,,6,,200,,2038:2040:2032,igte_AppStylingFocus,igte_AppStylingHover,igte_AppStylingNullText,igte_AppStylingInnerFocus,igte_AppStylingInnerHover","uid":"dpwinp_DepartureDate","buts":"igte_AppStylingButtonHover,igte_AppStylingButtonPressed,igte_AppStylingButtonDisabled,igte_AppStylingButtonFocus,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igte_customHover.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igte_customPress.gif,../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igte_customDisable.gif,"}}],,,["TextChanged:gl_UpdateNoOfNights","ValueChanged:gl_UpdateNoOfNights"]]}, null, null, $get("dpwinp_DepartureDate"));
});

document.getElementById('ctl31').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl31'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl32').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl32'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl33').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, document.getElementById('ctl33'));
}
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Infragistics.Web.UI.WebDropDown, {"id":"msd_HideWhenRestrictedBy_wdd_Property","name":"wdd_Property","props":[[[,,200,,,,,,,,,1,0,,,,,,0,,,0,,"",,,,,,1,,,0,,,,,,,,,,0,,,,,,,,],{"c":{"dropDownInputClass":"igdd_AppStylingValueDisplay","dropDownInputDisabledClass":"ig_AppStylingDisabled igdd_AppStylingValueDisplayDisabled","dropDownButtonDisabledImageUrl":"../../Styles/AppStyling/images/igdd_DropDownButtonDisabled.png","dropDownItemSelected":"igdd_AppStylingListItemSelected","dropDownItemDisabled":"igdd_AppStylingListItemDisabled","_pi":"[\"../../Styles/AppStyling/images/ig_ajaxIndicator.gif\",,,\"ig_AppStylingAjaxIndicator\",,1,,,,\"ig_AppStylingAjaxIndicatorBlock\",,3,,3,\"Async post\"]","chkAT":"Checked","dropDownInputFocusClass":"igdd_AppStylingValueDisplayFocus","dropDownButtonHoverImageUrl":"../../Styles/AppStyling/images/ig_dropdownbutton_hover.gif","dropDownButtonNormalImageUrl":"../../Styles/AppStyling/images/ig_dropdownbutton.gif","dropDownButtonPressedImageUrl":"../../Styles/AppStyling/images/ig_dropdownbutton_press.gif","dropDownItemHover":"igdd_AppStylingListItemHover","controlClass":"ig_AppStylingControl igdd_AppStylingControl","ocs":1,"pi":"[]","nullTextCssClass":"igdd_AppStylingNullText","dropDownInputHoverClass":"ig_AppStylingHover igdd_AppStylingValueDisplayHover","unchkAT":"Unchecked","pageCount":0,"controlAreaClass":"igdd_AppStylingControlArea","controlAreaFocusClass":"igdd_AppStylingControlFocus","dropDownButtonClass":"igdd_AppStylingDropDownButton","dropDownItemClass":"igdd_AppStylingListItem","dropDownItemActiveClass":"igdd_AppStylingListItemActive","controlDisabledClass":"ig_AppStylingDisabled igdd_AppStylingControlDisabled","uid":"msd_HideWhenRestrictedBy$wdd_Property","controlAreaHoverClass":"ig_AppStylingHover igdd_AppStylingControlHover"}}],,[{'0':[[,,,,,"Ceilings","10",,,,]],'1':[[,,,,,"Promo Code","20",,,,]],'2':[[,,,,,"User Access","30",,,,]],'3':[[,,,,,"Length of Stay","40",,,,]],'4':[[,,,,,"Occupants","50",,,,]],'5':[[163986,,,,,"Yield Management","60",,,,]],'6':[[,,,,,"Other Reasons","70",,,,]]}],["ValueChanged:WebDropDownValueChanged"]]}, null, null, $get("msd_HideWhenRestrictedBy_wdd_Property"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.ModalPopupBehavior, {"backgroundCssClass":"modalBackground","cancelControlID":"ModalDialog_btn_CloseModalDialogUC","dynamicServicePath":"/rezlynx1500/RLXWebForms/pak/wfrm_pak_PackageSearch.aspx","id":"mpeUC","popupControlID":"ModalDialog_mp_OpenModalDialogUC"}, null, null, $get("ModalDialog_btn_DummyUC"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, {"associatedUpdatePanelId":null,"displayAfter":0,"dynamicLayout":false}, null, null, $get("pi_Progress_up_PI"));
});
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Sys.Extended.UI.AlwaysVisibleControlBehavior, {"horizontalSide":1,"id":"pi_Progress_avce","verticalSide":1}, null, null, $get("pi_Progress_pnl_PIwrapper"));
});
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the actual code of the test - we've tried various sleep times...
driver.SwitchTo().Frame("Main");

```
        POM_CreateRes home3 = new POM_CreateRes(driver);

        //CreateReservation

       
        home3.AddBookingLine.Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

        //driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe#ModalDialog_mp_OpenModalDialogUC")));

        driver.SwitchTo().Frame("ModalDialog_if_OpenModalDialogUC");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        home3.Modal.Click();
       // home3.RatePlanSearch.Click();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);


    }
```

The line  `home3.AddBookingLine.Click();` triggers the modal...

[image: Click ADD to trigger popup]

[image: Modal]

Answer (score 1):

Your css selector seems incorrect. Try with this. cssselectror for `id` should be `tagname#attributeval` or only `#attributeval`

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("iframe#if_OpenModalDialog")));
```

Comment: Hi @KunduK. Thanks but sadly still the same result:  `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#ModalDialog_if_OpenModalDialogUC"}``

Comment: @DavidRedmayne : It seems different `id` which you have got an error not matches with the html you have posted?

Comment: If you use "inspect" you get the html as posted. If you use "View Frame Source" option you get `<iframe id="ModalDialog_if_OpenModalDialogUC"></iframe>' Neither/nor work :(!

Comment: @DavidRedmayne : Is it possible to share url to have a look?

Comment: Sadly it's proprietary software requiring logins etc. I could certainly do a screen share if that's possible?

Comment: @DavidRedmayne : Two things. 1) Have you added enough wait before accessing frame element? 2) it is possible to post view source of the modeldialog?

Comment: @DavidRedmayne : Had a look to page source. However couldn't  understand why need to switch `iframe`? which element were you trying to access?

Comment: Uploaded a couple of pics. Clicking the Add button on the first screen triggers the modal....we then need to click Rate Plan Search to proceed.

Comment: @DavidRedmayne : please inspect using F12 the `Rate Plan Search` element and post the entire html of the DOM tree? Then only I'll be able to see what's the problem. Thanks.

Comment: <a id="wbtn_Search" href="" onclick="gl_Postback('wbtn_Search');return false;" class="WebButton">Rate Plan Search</a>

Comment: I think you have Mis interpret my sentence or I might not able to explain I need the page full html where that element is so I can see Dom tree why not working.

Comment: the full page HTML is too large to post here :(

Comment: Well is your html look like this then you can post the html with actual value like this.

Comment: `<html>
<iframe name="xyz">
#document
  <html>
   ...
  </html>
  <iframe name="pqr">
  #document
  <html>
   ...
   <a id="wbtn_Search" href="" onclick="gl_Postback('wbtn_Search');return false;" class="WebButton">Rate Plan Search</a> 
  </html>
  </iframe>
</iframe>
</html>`